# Helpt with error C2259: cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++

I am trying to write this program for homework, and it wasn't throwing the C2259 error until I added the createList function. 
I can't figure out where this problem is originating from. I am fairly new at c++ so this might be an easy fix, but I am completely lost.

Here is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "binarySearchTree.h"
#include "orderedLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bSearchTreeType<int>  treeRoot; //error C2259: 'bSearchTreeType<int>'
    //cannot instantiate abstract class

    orderedLinkedList<int> newList;

    int num;

    cout << "Enter numbers ending with -999" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    while (num != -999)
    {
        treeRoot.insert(num);
        cin >> num;
    }

    cout << endl << "Tree nodes in inorder: ";
    treeRoot.inorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Tree Height: " << treeRoot.treeHeight()
        << endl;
    treeRoot.createList(newList);

    cout << "newList: ";
    newList.print();

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is binarySearchTree.h:

```
//Header File Binary Search Tree

#ifndef H_binarySearchTree
#define H_binarySearchTree
#include <iostream>
#include"binaryTree.h"

using namespace std;

template<class elemType>
class bSearchTreeType : public binaryTreeType < elemType >
{
public:
    //function to determine if searchItem is in search tree
    bool search(const elemType& searchItem) const;
    void insert(const elemType& insertItem);
    void deleteNode(const elemType& deleteItem);

    //update: void createList(const elemType& createItem);
    virtual void createList(const elemType& newList) = 0;   

private:
    void deleteFromTree(nodeType<elemType> *&p);
};

template<class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::createList(const elemType& createItem)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current;
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent;
    nodeType<elemType> *newNode;

    newNode = new nodeType < elemType > ;
    newNode->info = createItem;
    newNode->lLink = nullptr;
    newNode->rLink = nullptr;

    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = newNode;
    }
}

template<class elemType>
bool bSearchTreeType<elemType>::search(const elemType& searchItem)const
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current;
    bool found = false;

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Cannot search an empty tree." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        current = root;
        while (current != NULL && !found)
        {
            if (current->info == searchItem)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else if (current->info > searchItem)
            {
                current = current->lLink;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->rLink;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}

template<class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::insert(const elemType& insertItem)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current;
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent;
    nodeType<elemType> *newNode;

    newNode = new nodeType < elemType > ;
    newNode->info = insertItem;
    newNode->lLink = NULL;
    newNode->rLink = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        current = root;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;
            if (current->info == insertItem)
            {
                cout << "The item to be inserted is already in the tree";
                cout << "Duplicates are not allowed." << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->info > insertItem)
            {
                current = current->lLink;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->rLink;
            }
        }
        if (trailCurrent->info > insertItem)
        {
            trailCurrent->lLink = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;
        }
    }
}

template<class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::deleteNode(const elemType& deleteItem)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current;
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent;
    bool found = false;

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Cannot delete from an empty tree." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        current = root;
        trailCurrent = root;

        while (current != NULL && !found)
        {
            if (current->info == deleteItem)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;

                if (current->info > deleteItem)
                {
                    current = current->lLink;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current->rLink;
                }
            }
        }
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the tree." << endl;
        }
        else if (found)
        {
            if (current == root)
            {
                deleteFromTree(root);
            }
            else if (trailCurrent->info > deleteItem)
            {
                deleteFromTree(trailCurrent->lLink);
            }
            else
            {
                deleteFromTree(trailCurrent->rLink);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the tree." << endl;
        }
    }
}

template<class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::deleteFromTree(nodeType<elemType>* &p)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current; 
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent; 
    nodeType<elemType> *temp;

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: The node to be deleted is NULL." << endl;
    }
    else if (p->lLink == NULL && p->rLink == NULL)
    {
        temp = p;
        p = NULL;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if (p->lLink == NULL)
    {
        temp = p;
        p = temp->rLink;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if (p->rLink == NULL)
    {
        temp = p;
        p = temp->lLink;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
    {
        current = p->lLink;
        trailCurrent = NULL;

        while (current->rLink != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->rLink;
        }

        p->info = current->info;

        if (trailCurrent == NULL)
        {
            p->lLink = current->lLink;
        }
        else
        {
            trailCurrent->rLink = current->lLink;
        }

        delete current;
    }
}

#endif
```

Also, I am 112% sure my createList function is very wrong and will not create a tree of random numbers, so I could use a little help on that as well.

---

Update: binaryTree.h definition

```
#ifndef H_binaryTree
#define H_binaryTree

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//Define the node
template<class elemType>
struct nodeType
{
    elemType info;
    nodeType<elemType> *lLink;
    nodeType<elemType> *rLink;
};

template<class elemType>
class binaryTreeType
{
public:
    const binaryTreeType<elemType>& operator=(const binaryTreeType<elemType>&);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void inorderTraversal() const;
    void preorderTraversal() const;
    void postorderTraversal() const;
    int treeHeight() const;
    int treeNodeCount() const;
    int treeLeavesCount() const;
    void destroyTree();
    virtual bool search(const elemType& searchItem) const = 0;
    virtual void insert(const elemType& insertItem) = 0;
    virtual void deleteNode(const elemType& deleteItem) = 0;
    virtual void createList(const elemType& createItem) = 0;

    binaryTreeType(const binaryTreeType<elemType>& otherTree);
    binaryTreeType();
    ~binaryTreeType();

protected:
    nodeType<elemType> *root;

private:
    void copyTree(nodeType<elemType>*& copiedTreeRoot, nodeType<elemType>* otherTreeRoot);
    void destroy(nodeType<elemType>* &p);
    void inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p)const;
    void preorder(nodeType<elemType> *p)const;
    void postorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const;
    int height(nodeType<elemType> *p)const;
    int max(int x, int y) const;
    int nodeCount(nodeType<elemType> *p)const;
    int leavesCount(nodeType<elemType> *p)const;
};

template <class elemType>
binaryTreeType<elemType>::binaryTreeType()
{
    root = NULL;
}

template <class elemType>
bool binaryTreeType<elemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (root == NULL);
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorderTraversal() const
{
    inorder(root);
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::preorderTraversal() const
{
    preorder(root);
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::postorderTraversal() const
{
    postorder(root);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeHeight() const
{
    return height(root);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeNodeCount() const
{
    return nodeCount(root);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeLeavesCount() const
{
    return leavesCount(root);
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::copyTree(nodeType<elemType>* &copiedTreeRoot,
nodeType<elemType>* otherTreeRoot)
{
    if (otherTreeRoot == NULL)
        copiedTreeRoot = NULL;
    else
    {
        copiedTreeRoot = new nodeType<elemType>;
        copiedTreeRoot->info = otherTreeRoot->info;
        copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->lLink, otherTreeRoot->lLink);
        copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->rLink, otherTreeRoot->rLink);
    }
} 

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->lLink);
        cout << p->info << " ";
        inorder(p->rLink);
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::preorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->info << " ";
        preorder(p->lLink);
        preorder(p->rLink);
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::postorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        postorder(p->lLink);
        postorder(p->rLink);
        cout << p->info << " ";
    }
}

//Overload the assignment operator
template <class elemType>
const binaryTreeType<elemType>& binaryTreeType<elemType>::operator=(const binaryTreeType<elemType>& otherTree)
{
    if (this != &otherTree) //avoid self-copy
    {
        if (root != NULL) //if the binary tree is not empty,
            //destroy the binary tree
            destroy(root);

        if (otherTree.root == NULL) //otherTree is empty
            root = NULL;
        else
            copyTree(root, otherTree.root);
    }//end else

    return *this;
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::destroy(nodeType<elemType>* &p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        destroy(p->lLink);
        destroy(p->rLink);
        delete p;
        p = NULL;
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::destroyTree()
{
    destroy(root);
}

//copy constructor
template <class elemType>
binaryTreeType<elemType>::binaryTreeType
(const binaryTreeType<elemType>& otherTree)
{
    if (otherTree.root == NULL) //otherTree is empty
        root = NULL;
    else
        copyTree(root, otherTree.root);
}

//Destructor
template <class elemType>
binaryTreeType<elemType>::~binaryTreeType()
{
    destroy(root);
}

template<class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::height
(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + max(height(p->lLink), height(p->rLink));
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::max(int x, int y) const
{
    if (x >= y)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::nodeCount(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    return nodeCount(root);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::leavesCount(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    return leavesCount(root);
}

#endif
```

Comment: What's the definition of binaryTreeType<>?

Comment: I added the binaryTree.h file to the original post-- see update

Answer (score 2):

```
virtual void createList(const elemType& newList) = 0 ;
                          ///                    ~~~~ shouldn't be used in derived class
```

The pure virtual function should only be present in your abstract class which I assume is `binaryTreeType`

Answer (score 0):

You have to override createList method since it's a virtual.

Comment: But you haven't implemented your virtual method inside abstract class yet.